# How I can get a unique device id using javascript in a browser?

Tags: javascript

I want to build an authentication system that forces everyone to "register" the device using an OTP.

And if the device it's not registered can't use the app, until OTP passed.

The problem I'm having is that some of the libraries that I have used (Fingerprint, Device-UUID), is that if you open in a different browser on the same computer/mobile or something changes in the browser, it will generate a new different ID, which is not what I need.

I want to detect the device no matter what browser or what changes, if it still the same device

I wanted to access the MAC address or SN of the computer/mobile. Still, it seems you can't access that information for security reasons, so I'm asking what the "available browser information" would keep the same "information" no matter what browser it uses?

I appreciate any tips or information.

Comment: As said in the OP, I have already tried with that library but it generates IDs based on information that can change easily. Thank you anyway, I think that's the only solution for now ...

Comment: right, there is no official way. that hash solution is the 'hacky' way. Maybe rethink your authentication structure, there's gotta be a different way than restricting a specific device. Or restrict it to a single "known browser" and save a local cookie.